# Solving System of Equations using Gauss/Gauss-Jordan (Matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, jordan-normal-form, gaussian-elimination

System of equations
$$\begin{align*}
    x  -2y +3z   &= 2\\
    2x  -3y +8z   &= 7\\
    3x  -4y +13z &= 8
\end{align*}$$

In a augmented matrix, $3\times 4$
$$\left(\begin{array}{crc|c}
    1 &-2 &3 &2\\
    2 &-3 &8& 7 \\
    3 &-4 &13& 8\\
\end{array}\right).$$

Above are the equations/rows. Using these row operations: a constant number times a row, interchanging/switching equations/row, and lastly adding two equations/rows together after multiplying one of them by a constant -- I am still unable to solve and end up having to cancel out a part of the diagonal of the matrix when trying to achieve a result similar or equal to the identity matrix. By cancel out I mean turn into 0 which makes it not recoverable using these operations. This is a problem when trying to reach a upper triangular matrix (row echelon or reduced row echelon but in this case whichever).

A similar situation seems to be the case with two unknowns and the same three number of equations

$$\begin{align*}
    x  +y   &= 1\\
    9x -y   &= 0\\
    x  -19y &= -17
\end{align*}$$

Comment: The coefficient matrix is not invertible: that's why you are getting a row of $0$s in the coefficient matrix. This system has either no solutions (if the system is inconsistent) or infinitely many solutions. You can reach row echelon and reduced row echelon forms with a row of zeros, that is not an obstacle.

Comment: Is what you got correct? Since the bottom right should be 1, no? I have tried switching rows or looking for some sort of multiples to avoid cancelling out but that does not seem to work at all

Comment: You can't avoid "cancelling" because the system is inconsistent.

Comment: The final paragraph is completely disconnected from the rest of the question. No explanation, no context, no nothing. I guess we are expected to read your mind as to what it is supposed to be doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is inconsistent: the second equation minus twice the first equation gives $y+2z=3$, but the third equation minus three times the second equation gives $2y+4z=2$. Those two equations are not consistent, so the system has no solutions. You can see that  when doing Gaussian elimination:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{crc|c}
    1 &-2 &3 &2\\
    2 &-3 &8& 7 \\
    3 &-4 &13& 8\\
\end{array}\right) &\stackrel{R_2-2R_1}{\longrightarrow} \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
3 & -4 & 13 & 8
\end{array}\right) \stackrel{R_3-3R_1}{\longrightarrow} \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 2 & 4 & 2
\end{array}\right)\\
&\stackrel{R_3-2R_2}{\longrightarrow} \left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -4
\end{array}\right) \stackrel{-\frac{1}{4}R_3}{\longrightarrow}
\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & -2 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$
Both the coefficient and the augmented matrices are now in row echelon form: the first nonzero entry of each row is a $1$, and the $1$ in each row appears to the right of the $1$ in the previous row, and all rows of $0$s are at the bottom.

Since the rank of the reduced coefficient matrix is $2$, but the rank of the augmented matrix is $3$, the system is inconsistent. You can continue from here to get the reduced row echelon form, but it doesn't suddenly "fix" the problem:
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{crc|c}
1 & -2 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0& 1
\end{array}\right)&\stackrel{R_1-2R_3}{\longrightarrow}
\left(\begin{array}{crc|c}
1 & -2 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right) \stackrel{R_2-3R_3}{\longrightarrow}
\left(\begin{array}{crc|c} 
1 & -2 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\\
&\stackrel{R_1+2R_2}{\longrightarrow}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 7 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$
This is in reduced row-echelon form (the added condition is that the leading $1$s in each row are the only nonzero entries in their columns), but again you see that it corresponds to an inconsistent system.

Now, suppose that the last equation was $3x-4y+13z=12$, instead of $8$. Then in the third step of the reduction above we would have gotten the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{crc|c}
1 & -2 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 2 & 4 & 6
\end{array}\right)\stackrel{R_3-2R_2}{\longrightarrow}
\left(\begin{array}{crc|c}
1 & -2 & 3 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
This is a perfectly fine row-echelon form matrix;  it's just that you will end up with one free variable and infinitely many solutions. You can then proceed to do the reduced row echelon form by adding twice the second row to the first row  and you would get
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 7 & 8\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
which gives the solutions
$$\begin{align*}
x &= 8 - 7t\\
y &= 3 - 2t\\
z &= t
\end{align*},\qquad t\text{ arbitrary.}$$

Comment: How would this have differed if the linear system contained the same number of equations but rather than 3 unknowns (x,y,z) there were only 2 unknowns? In this case would there only need to be one 0 on the bottom left corner of the matrix before solving? I have added to the end of my post an example of this.

Comment: Is it the same case of not being able to have a solution?

Comment: @PauIPogba It works the same way. A system with more equations than unknown may have no solutions, may have exactly one solution, or may have infinitely many solutions. An underdetermined system (more unknowns than equations) may have no solutions or infinitely many; but an overdetermined system and a square system may have no solutions, exactly one, or infinitely many. The system you have is inconsistent (first two equations yield $x=\frac{1}{10}$ and $y=\frac{9}{10}$, and then the third equation doesn't work.

Comment: @PauIPogba I do not understand your "only need to be one $0$ on the bottom left corner of the matrix before solving" comment. To me, it reads like nonsense. Do you now know *what* the definition of "row echelon form" is, or what Gaussian elimination is? If that's the case, it would certainly explain your confusion. There is **no** requirement about what the matrix looks like *before* you start Gaussian elimination.

Comment: I meant when producing an augmented matrix for the linear equations, you would end up with a 2 by 3 and a good way to achieve gauss/gauss-jordan is by ensuring a diagonol line of 1's and for the bottom of the matrix to contain 0's (after the elimination of course). Because it would be a 2x3, I was curious to know how this would then apply.

Comment: And when you say no solution, is that a final (of course excluding where you have to change the question to get a solution)? So the end point would be that there is no solution. And by that do you mean on a graph it would be parallel lines...?

Comment: @PauIPogba: In a system with three equations in two unknowns, the augmented matrix for the system would be a $3\times 3$. "ensuring a diagonal of $1$s"... No. You do Gaussian elimination by doing Gaussian elimination, not by trying to get something which may be impossible to get. I ask again: do you actually know what Gaussian elimination *is* and what you are trying to accomplish with it? Because it does not look like you do.

Comment: @PauIPogba When I say "no solution", I mean, unsurprisingly, that the system has no solutions. Performing row operations does not change the solution set, so this is about the system, not just "a final". Parallel lines make no sense for a system with three unknowns. For the system of three equations in two unknowns it means there is no point that is simultaneously on all three lines. It need not be because any of the. are parallel. Your example has no solutions, but no two of the lines determined by the separate equations are parallel.